# Changing Adapter properties from Activity/Fragment

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a `ListView` with a `ContextMenu` built in.  The menu allows user to rename an item property in a `TextView`.

However, upon scrolling down, and coming back up, the old name appears again.

I understand why:  The `adapter` is not being updated.

For example:  in the `adapter` I have an object for each row:  `Review`.  Then there is a property called `name`.

So in the `getView()` I do:

```
Review r = getItem(position);
name = r.name;
myTextView.setText(name);
```

Now if users update that `TextView` from the `Fragment` (via the `ContextMenu`), how do I access this property (name) *and update the `adapter`/object that same position?*

Comment: In the callback for the `ContextMenu` you can retrieve the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html . Use the `position` parameter and update the `Review` item from the list(passed to the adapter) for that position and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the position for which contextMenu was created in the listView you can try the below.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo(); 
    int position = (int) info.id; 
    // This is the position in the ListView for which contextMenu was created. 
    // get and update your object and notify the adapter. 
    Review r = myListView.getAdapter().getItem(position); 
    r.name = "whatever new thing"; 
    myListView.getAdapter(). notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In this code we are updating the `Review` object in `Adapter` with the new value and notifying the adapter of the change that has taken place. This is will in turn refresh your list and will use the new value that was just supplied.